# What is the adverb in this sentence? It was dark outside and an icy wind made me shiver

Tags: adverbs

It was dark outside and an icy wind made me shiver.

Comment: Who said there's an adverb?

Comment: Be aware that different grammars analyse the 'adverb' class in different ways.

Comment: This was a question in my son's, Year 5, English skills book.

Answer (score 2):

The adverb is "outside"; adverbs are words that can modify or add precisions to *adjectives*, *verbs* or other *adverbs* and as well *clauses* ([ref.](https://www.gingersoftware.com/content/grammar-rules/adverb/)).

Once you have this definition in mind you can start looking identifying those grammatical words in your sentences, provided you already have a good idea about the others; all this knowledge about the nature of words must be approached as a whole.
In this sentence, you find the following grammatical words
verbs:                                          was, made, shiver
nouns:                                         wind
pronouns:                                   it, me
adjectives:                                  dark, icy
conjunction of coordination: and          
adverb:                                       outside

After you have eliminated the words easier to recognize you are left with words that can be adverbs, but here is another characterization of adverbs that is worth considering if you want to become familiar with this grammatical concept. (same ref. as above)

> Specifically, adverbs provide a description of how, where, when, in what manner and to what extent something is done or happens. Normally, we can spot an adverb by the fact that it often ends in –ly, but there are lots of adverbs that don’t end in this way. Moreover, adverbs can be used in many combinations with each other.

Since "outside" makes precise **where** it **is**  dark it must be an adverb. Since it shows a place ("outside" is the place found out of the building(s) taken as reference) it is called an **adverb of place**. It adds precision to the verbal form "was".

Comment: I'm not sure who contribute to 'Ginger'. Pullum, Huddlestone et al class 'outside' etc in such constructions as _intransitive prepositions_, at least partly modelling on 'It was dark outside the house / castle / hostel ...'. Hence @Hot Licks' comment.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth This classification as preposition is well recognized, I think, this word is entered in the SOED as adj., n., adv. and prep. The particular category of preposition (intransitive) is not clear to me; for instance I wouldn't be able to tell whether it is intransitive or not in this example given by the dictionary: "sitting outside the house and not being able to get in.". However it seems to me that the noun after is essential in order to speak of preposition.

Comment: If a preposition has an overt complement (and the traditional view is that it _must_ do), as 'outside' in your example here does ('outside _the house_'), it's 'transitive'.